# JavaScript and CSS settings fail unexpectedly: The files were not created

Tags: javascript, theming, 7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal Commons site has no style after installation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19628/drupal-commons-site-has-no-style-after-installation)

See the Drupal Commons site running on boysday.org

well how to start. i am new to drupal and I have serious flaws during the installation; Tried it dozens of times.I get warnings about too many files open. Somebody gave me the advice to do the adjustments in the administrative section (admin/settings/performance).

On "Bandwidth optimizations,"  the option "Optimize CSS files" and "Optimize JavaSript files" were enabled. I have tried to switch off; for testing and customize my Drupal Commons install it's better to disable as to have CSS and JavaScript development support with tools like "Firebug" using Firefox.

I tried to do so, and got back a very interesting message.

> Performance
>
> The file could not be created.
>   The file could not be created.

Can this be caused by the fact the folders in /home/vhost/WWW/mysite/sites/default/files were all owned by the wwwrun user? What can I do?

There are no pictures, and no CSS. Is there any right or permission problem?

> warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/vhost/WWW/mysite/modules/system/system.module on line 1020.
>   warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/vhost/WWW/mysite/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.
>   warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vhost/WWW/mysite/includes/theme.inc on line 1832.

Comment: But OP is different account?

Comment: @MPD A question is a duplicated if it is asking the same thing asked in another question; the fact the question is asked by another user doesn't matter.

Comment: hello FR6 hello MPD - hello kiamlauno. Thx for he answer and the comments. well i have serious troubles on all the server. I guess that i have to upgrad the server to apache 2.2 - the old server-horse apache 1.3. is ment to be depriciated! well what do you suggest!?

Comment: @zero, is this the same problem/question as FVR linked to above?  The original version of the question was for the same website.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, potential duplicate, but I would not say they were exact dups.  The OP should at least have the chance to address whether it was a duplicate and delete it themselves.

Comment: @MPD In this case, the question is a duplicate because both the questions are referring to Drupal Commons, and in both the cases the issue the files not being created. FR6 doesn't have the privilege of voting to close, and he added a comment, but he is right about the question being a duplicate; he just started the comment with "possible duplicate" because he saw the automatic comments generated when the first user votes to close a question.

Comment: The fact the user linked to the same site seems a little suspicious; it could be both the users maintain the same site, but I don't see any reason for asking a question when another maintainer already asked it. That is not what makes the difference between a duplicate question and a not duplicate question, but it is a good catch from your side. Why did the OP refer to the same site? Does that mean the OP was aware of the other question? Is the OP asking a question because a real problem, or did he simply copy another question?

Comment: hello dear moderators: you do a very well job here - and have all my respect. i am the guy who is in trouble and does not know how to solve the issues
i am new to drupal and to this forum here. For Account-Creation i was asked to sign in with stack-exchange/overflow-account. The first login was yesterday from office - As i logged me in today (at home) with that way i saw that i have somewhat like two identities. That is not what is wanted. To be frank-i love stackexchange, but i am a novice regarding the technique that is used here. The user-managenemt is very clever,a bit too clever for me.

Comment: but back to drupal: i have very very much issues with drupal and i do not know how to solve.plz plz dont bear with me! I have a dedicated server and i try to find out if i have to drop this server - since it is too old and to weak to cope with drupal.
Therfore i do some test-installations (on diffferent domains), Each time i install i do some little shift in the configuration - in 
oder to find out where this damned problem origins.. where it is rootet.

Comment: Conclusion: so you are right - i am the poor guy  who can t go ahead and who has the (allmost same) issues on different trials of intallation.
but for now: i do not post new questions with similar content - but i am going to work out all the answers and try to solve the issue. 

And last but not least - i try to learn more about the stack-user-account-principles that are some what like a mystic thing to me.

Answer (score 0):

As you already suggested, this is most likely a file permission problem. Make sure the entire directory under sites\default\files is writable by the apache user, often this is called www-data.

To get you going maybe download [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) for your platform and get your first Drupal installation working locally.