# permisssions set to 755 - image upload is not possible - in drupal-commons 6x 24. 

Tags: media, users, theming, 7

hello and good day hope  you are all well!

**newest update:**
Now i have created a second installation with partly other conditions:(haviing permissions 755 with **user vhost: www** on /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default The selected file xxxxx could not be uploaded. Only JPEG, PNG and GIF images are allowed. Well this is a new error - i had not this error before - what can i do. Guess that i have a made a big step... what do you think!?

Here the original-thread-start: just installed a drupal -commons version 6x 24:

when i try to upload images i get errors - and after doing some search in the system and the adminstration-controll i fould out: the reported error

image upload is not possible - in drupal-commons version 6x 24 {released on jan 18th ):  i have done some research and found out that i have: 755 -  in directory sites/default/files

Allthough i have the **permisssions set to 755 -**

what can i do here - just lemme know!

The directory sites/default/files is not writable
see the path where i i have recogniczed the error

http://schulcenter.org/?q=admin/build/themes/settings

The directory sites/default/files is not writable

Well what can i do here?!

**update:** thx alexandru and Mpd - thx for the answers; well everytime i touch the permissions i get  lost.- (i have troubles n issues with permissions and file users. see here https://superuser.com/questions/382792/setgid-bit-always-unset-when-changing-file-permissions  hmmm - well MPD guess that you are right and i am pretty lost -here . what can i do now??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set files directory permissions to 777 to make it writable by "others". As I understand you set it to 755 and expect to be writable? 755 means all for the owner, read and exec by group and read and exec by others.

**EDIT**: As MPD said, if the owner of the files is same user as the one apache runs as than files directory doesn't have to be 777. 755 is enough and it is also recommended.

Comment: hello dear alexander - great to  hear from you. well this is just good news. You advice me to set it to 777.  if i got you right then only with this setting i am able to upload images  - for the users and the groups for example. well i guess that i now have understood what i made wrong. -i am going to   set the permissons to 777. and afterwards i come badk and report all my findings  . greetings

Comment: This isn't really true.  sites/whatever/files can be 755 as long as it is owned by the user that Apache runs as (eg, apache, www, or nobody).  In fact, it can be argued that 777 is a security concern.

Comment: hi MPD thx for commenting. well i tried to change to 2777 and then all gets lost. I loose the style at all. guess that this is rooted in my server that runs a   bad ftp-server - see here http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=38734#38734 and of course here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19628/drupal-commons-site-has-no-style-after-installation  and here  as well http://superuser.com/questions/382792/setgid-bit-always-unset-when-changing-file-permissions  hmmm - well MPD guess that you are right and i am pretty lost -here . what can i do now??

Comment: Before I run install.php, I chown -R apache.apache docroot/.  When that is done, I chown -R someuser.someuser docroot/ and  chown -R apache.apache docroot/sites/default/files.  Typically, someuser is the same user I drush and ssh as.

Comment: hello dear MPD - thx  for the hints - i will discuss this matters with my serveradmin. and i want to install drush and work accordingly

Comment: What OS are you running?  Also, I believe it should `chown -R apache:apache docroot` instead of `chown -R apache.apache docroot`  On my install of Ubuntu the command is `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`  Obviously the users and directories would need to match your setup, but do replace the `.` with a `:`  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

Comment: hi Citricguy - i run OpenSuselinux - does that help!? I am eagerly waitin to ge the things fixed and the bugs nailed down. At the weekend i can do more trials - install drush and lots of things more. i come back later the days and report

Comment: @Citricguy, chown usually works with both . and :  Using a colon is a somewhat recent change.  The original BSD version of the command used . but modern OS allow . in usernames, hence the change to :  Old habits die hard...

Comment: Hello dear MPD and Cityguy - thx for the replies - lots of stuff to learn! Many many thanks for all. I will dig deeper in to all your advices and will benefit  from all your hints. Greetings

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! @MPD indeed you don't need 777 if the owner of the files is the same user as the one that Apache runs as. I'll edit the question to reflect this. zero, did you manage to fix it eventually?

Comment: Hello Alexandru - thx for the reply.  It begins that icannot upload an image -into the  folder /home/vhost/WWW/schulcenter.org/sites/default/files
I was not able to fix it. First of all - regarding the user: my serveradmin works with the SETGID-BIT and user vhost:vhost
Bad is: everytime i touch the chmod - i loose the setgit-bit:  well i tried to change to 2777 and then all gets lost. I loose the style at all!!!!! Well Alexandru - i struggle with these issues for months now - i guess that i have to upload drush and work with drush to get the issues nailed down!? What do you think!?

Comment: Again Alexandru - again thx for all: Guess that this is rooted in my server that runs a bad ftp-server - see here http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=38734#38734 and 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19628/drupal-commons-site-has-no-style-after-installation
http://superuser.com/questions/382792/setgid-bit-always-unset-when-changing-file-permissions
what can i do now! Well Alexandru - i struggle with these issues for months now - i guess that i have to upload drush and work with drush to get the issues nailed down!? What do you think!?
Love to hear from you!!!!

Comment: Now i have created a second installation with **partly other conditions:**(haviing permissions 755 with **user vhost: www** on /home/vhost/WWW/campus-24.com/sites/default

The selected file  xxxxx  could not be uploaded. **Only JPEG, PNG and GIF images are allowed.**

Well this is a new error - i had not this error before - what can i do.  Guess that i have a made a big step... 

what do you think!?